# How to perform Action in Rest API

Tags: rest

I try to create a pdf ON Server but what will be the Rest URL? I.e. For a List of all Clubs in one Region  GET /clubListForRegion/3

Thanks!

Comment: Will the PDF be created on the fly? What REST framework do you use on which server?

Comment: I've no special framework. What would be your advice? Yes it will be created on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

The design of the resource depends on your application domain. If you offer some service for browsing different entertainment branches and you can drill down into certain regions I would propose

```
GET /regions/north-east/entertainment/clubs
```

and the **representation** of this collection of club resources would be a PDF.
If you are offering some service specialised on browsing clubs, you could shorten the hierarchy or use a query parameter:

```
GET /clubs/techno?region=north-east
```

If the on the fly creation of the PDF takes a noticeable amount of time, I would propose a POST on the resource instead. The response could contain a link to the final PDF and possibly a link to query the status of the PDF creation process.